# Delay using Promise.all() in a for

Tags: promise

I need to add a delay when executing each promises in `Promise.all()`.

**My code :**

```
  for (let i = 0; i < stockDiff; i++) {
    var invoiceObject = {
      sellProducts: [{
        quantity: 1,
        description: '<p style="margin: 0;">' + findedProduct.name + '</p>',
        digital_access: findedProduct.digital_access,
        forced_ttc_price: parseFloat(findedProduct.ttc_price, 10),
        offer_amount: null
      }],
      totalHt: findedProduct.ht_price,
      totalTtc: findedProduct.ttc_price
    };
    promises.push(InvoiceController.createInvoice('À la commande', null, null, 2, null, null, null, null, null, null, invoiceObject.sellProducts));
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    request.flash('success', 'Stock mis à jour !');
    response.redirect('/product/_index');
  });
```

My function `InvoiceController.createInvoice()` returns a promise :

```
function createInvoice(rule, publicNote, privateNote, state, customerId, userId, address, complementaryAddress, postalCode, city, products, services, productPackages) {

  var productsPromise, servicesPromise, productPackagesPromise,
      promises = [];

  return InvoiceModel.create({
    date: new Date(),
    rule: rule,
    public_note: publicNote,
    private_note: privateNote,
    state: 1,
    address: address,
    complementary_address: complementaryAddress,
    postal_code: postalCode,
    city: city,
    customerId: customerId,
    userId: userId
  }).then(function(createdInvoice) {

    if (products) {
      productsPromise = _.map(products, function(product) {
        return InvoiceProductModel.create({
          invoiceId: createdInvoice.id,
          quantity: product.quantity,
          description: product.description,
          forced_ttc_price: product.forced_ttc_price,
          offer_amount: product.offer_amount
        });
      });
    }

    if (services) {
      servicesPromise = _.map(services, function(service) {
        return InvoiceServiceModel.create({
          invoiceId: createdInvoice.id,
          quantity: service.quantity,
          description: service.description,
          forced_ttc_price: service.forced_ttc_price,
          offer_amount: service.offer_amount,
          start: service.start,
          end: service.end
        });
      });
    }

    if (productPackages) {
      productPackagesPromise = _.map(productPackages, function(productPackage) {
        return InvoiceServiceModel.create({
          invoiceId: createdInvoice.id,
          description: productPackage.description,
          forced_ttc_price: productPackage.forced_ttc_price,
          offer_amount: productPackage.offer_amount,
          start: productPackage.start,
          end: productPackage.end
        });
      });
    }

    promises = _.flattenDeep(productsPromise.concat(servicesPromise).concat(productPackagesPromise));

    return Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
      return createdInvoice.update({
        state: state
      }).then(function(updatedInvoice) {
        return Promise.resolve(updatedInvoice);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: you want to execute promises in order ? or what, it is not clear, what you want to achieve exactly

Comment: I want to execute all promises an when all promises are well executed I need to redirect the page. The order is not important.

Comment: ok, so why is the delay ?

Comment: Because when creating my invoice using `InvoiceController.createInvoice()` an invoice number is generated, but this one is not increased when using the function in a `for`.

Comment: then probably the issue is in the createInvoice function. As I do not see any problem with this bit of code

Comment: You can see now my entire function in my edited post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226926/discussion-between-serges-and-tonymx227).

Comment: Promises are not "executed", promises can only be waited for. You can't put a delay "between" the promises passed to `Promise.all`. You need to delay your `for` iterations themselves.